# How to reference an exported function inside of a Node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

How can I reference an exported function inside a Node.js module like:

```
'use strict';

const orm = require('orm');
module.exports = orm.createModel('Accounts');

const Project = require('./Project.js');

// this should be the result of orm.createModel('Accounts')
this.hasMany(Project, 'projects');
```

However, my linter is complaining about `possible strict violation`. Is there a way to do this without defining a variable?

Comment: Are the first 5 lines the content of of `./Project.js`? I'm not understanding your question and your file structure.

Comment: No, it is `./Account.js`. Basically trying to ovoid doing `const Account = orm.createModel('Accounts');` and then `module.exports = Account;`.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Don't understand where the possible strict violation is?  Can you give us more info on what the linter says and what exact line of code it's complaining about?

Comment: Linter complaining about using `this.hasMany()`.

Comment: And, what are you expecting `this` to refer to in `this.hasMany()`?  Why not use the actual object variable name instead of `this`?  In the future, if you expect me to see comments that are a direct response to anyone in a timely fashion, you should start them with `@username` so that user will get notified.  It was only by accident that I saw your response.

Comment: I recommend using the actual variable instead of `this` keyword here. and also exporting in the last line of the file to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jshint/jslint, in strict mode, 'this' that not inside a constructor function will cause 'possible strict violation'.

Try the code below, and you will find that only thrid `console.log(this)` don't cause 'possible strict violation'.

```
'use strict';

console.log(this);

function test() {
  console.log(this);
}

function Test() {
  console.log(this);
}
```